# Delphi 2010: Confusing generic type TList scenario? Pass by value or reference?

Tags: delphi, generics, record, tlist

I encountered a problem some days ago while working with Generic TList in the middle of a project. I tested it in a simple test project and got the same problem. Here is the exact code:

```
type
  TMyPoint = record
    x: Integer;
    y: Integer;
  end;

  TShape = record
    Corners: TList<TMyPoint>;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Shape_List: TList<TShape>;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Shape: TShape;
  FirstPoint: TMyPoint;
  SecondPoint: TMyPoint;
  Temp: TMyPoint;
begin
  // Create the corners list
  Shape.Corners := TList<TMyPoint>.Create;
  // Add the first point to corners
  FirstPoint.x := 10;
  FirstPoint.y := 20;
  Shape.Corners.Add(FirstPoint);
  // Add the shape to the Shape_List
  Shape_List.Add(Shape);

  // Clear the shape corners
  Shape.Corners.Clear;

  // Add another point to corners
  SecondPoint.x := 100;
  SecondPoint.y := 200;
  Shape.Corners.Add(SecondPoint);

  // Show the x of the first point of the first shape
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Shape_List[0].Corners[0].x);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Shape_List := TList<TShape>.Create;
end;
```

The Label1.Caption will be **100** not **10** ! Why is it like this? I thought `TList.Add(const value)` is pass-by-value not pass-by-reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added some comments to your procedure to point out exactly where the "bug" is.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Shape: TShape;
  FirstPoint: TMyPoint;
  SecondPoint: TMyPoint;
  Temp: TMyPoint;
begin
  // Create the corners list
  Shape.Corners := TList<TMyPoint>.Create; // We create a new TList<TMyPOint> OBJECT. Shape.Corners is a reference
  // Add the first point to corners
  FirstPoint.x := 10;
  FirstPoint.y := 20;
  Shape.Corners.Add(FirstPoint); // Add FirstPoint to the list we created at step 1.
  // Add the shape to the Shape_List
  Shape_List.Add(Shape); // Add a copy of the Shape record to the Shape_List

  // Clear the shape corners
  Shape.Corners.Clear; // Clear the Shape.Corners reference. This effectively clears the list of corners
                       // in the Shape you just added to Shape_List because it contains the same
                       // reference.

  // Add another point to corners
  SecondPoint.x := 100;
  SecondPoint.y := 200;
  Shape.Corners.Add(SecondPoint); // Add a new point to the Corners list. Remamber, Corners is actually
                                  // a reference. The first Shape you added to Shape_List contains a copy
                                  // of this exact same reference, so you're effectively adding a first point
                                  // to both Shape.Corners and Shape_List[0].Corners.

  // Show the x of the first point of the first shape
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Shape_List[0].Corners[0].x); // Yup, you just added that point, so you get 100
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for making it clear to me. What I was thinking is when a copy of the record is made, a copy of TList in it is also made, which was a wrong assumption.

Comment: are you sure about "array of TMyPoint"? AFAIK dynamic arrays are not "copy-on-write" as strings are. Even the help mentions this.

Comment: Like Uwe, I also wonder does a dynamic array would solve the problem? Does it really behave like string?

Comment: @Uwe Raabe, @Flom: made a mistake, dynamic array is not copy-on-write. Deleted the comment to make sure no one takes as "truth".

Answer (score 4):

After adding the `FirstPoint`, you `Clear` the `Corners` (after that, the list is empty). Then you add `SecondPoint` which becomes the first element (index 0).

Edit: To illustrate:

```
var
  Shape1, Shape2: TShape;
begin
  Shape1.Corners := TList<TMyPoint>.Create;
  Shape2 := Shape1;
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('Shape1.Corners: $%.8x', [Integer(Shape1.Corners)])));
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('Shape2.Corners: $%.8x', [Integer(Shape2.Corners)])));
end;
```

`Shape1.Corners` and `Shape2.Corners` point to the same list.

Comment: You didn't read the code carefully. I showed the first corner of the first shape in the 'Shape_List' not the local variable. The change is made after adding the shape to the Shape_List. I cleared the corners of the local variable (Shape) not the one in the list (which should be a copy of Shape)

Comment: Correction: the local variable Shape may be a copy (since it's a record) but the Corners field is a reference. So Shape may be a copy of Shape_List[0] but Shape.Corners points to the same list as Shape_List[0].Corners.

Comment: +1, this is happening because Shape.Corners is a reference. Added an answer with comments to the original code to make this a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is passed by reference since it is passed as a constant parameter (see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Collections.TList.Add).

Comment: As the list items are records the list will still contain copies of the items added.

Comment: So what is the difference between 'const value' and 'var value'? Are both of them pass by reference?!

Comment: @Flom Enol - exactly. The difference is that `var value` allows to modify the parameter in the function/procedure it is passed to while `const value` does not.

Comment: @Flom Enol - look here for more explanation ( http://vcldeveloper.com/articles/different-function-parameter-modifiers-in-delphi/ )

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for your answer. I will check out the article.